# TypeError: utf_8_encode() argument 1 must be str, not bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, typeerror

I'm working on RESTful APIs as part of a Udacity training:

https://www.udacity.com/course/designing-restful-apis--ud388

I recieved starter code (**find_restaurant.py**) and the assignment is to complete this code. I'm trying to complete this code step-by-step.

When I run: "find_restaurant.py", it returns the below traceback.

I have searched the internet (incl. stack overflow) and found some relevant topics, however I sill don't understand the issue.
Can someone please help me to **understand** the TypeError?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\ds_dev\Udacity\fullstack-nanodegree-vm\find_restaurant.py", line 37, in <module>
    find_restaurant("Pizza", "Tokyo, Japan")

  File "D:\ds_dev\Udacity\fullstack-nanodegree-vm\find_restaurant.py", line 23, in find_restaurant
    print(meal_type)

  File "C:\Users\zeerm\.conda\envs\spyder\lib\codecs.py", line 378, in write
    self.stream.write(data)

  File "C:\Users\zeerm\.conda\envs\spyder\lib\codecs.py", line 377, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)

TypeError: utf_8_encode() argument 1 must be str, not bytes
```

**geocode.py:**

```
import json
import httplib2


def geocode_location(address_string):
    """Retrieve latitude and longitude for a location string.

    Http GET request to Google Maps API for retrieving latitude and longitude
    for a location string.
    """
    
    address = address_string.replace(" ", "%20")
    key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    url = (f'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?' +
           f'address={address}&key={key}')
    h = httplib2.Http()
    result = json.loads(h.request(url, 'GET')[1])
    latitude = result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
    longitude = result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
    return (latitude, longitude)
```

**find_restaurant.py**

```
import json
import sys
import codecs
import httplib2
from geocode import geocode_location

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stderr)

FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_SECRET = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

def find_restaurant(meal_type, location):
    """ # TODO: Descripe function."""

    # 1. Use getGeocodeLocation to get the latitude and longitude coordinates of the location string.
    print(meal_type)
    lat_lng = geocode_location(location)
    print(lat_lng)
    # 2.  Use foursquare API to find a nearby restaurant with the latitude, longitude, and mealType strings.
    # HINT: format for url will be something like https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=20130815&ll=40.7,-74&query=sushi

    # 3. Grab the first restaurant
    # 4. Get a  300x300 picture of the restaurant using the venue_id (you can change this by altering the 300x300 value in the URL or replacing it with 'orginal' to get the original picture
    # 5. Grab the first image
    # 6. If no image is available, insert default a image url
    # 7. Return a dictionary containing the restaurant name, address, and image url


if __name__ == '__main__':
    find_restaurant("Pizza", "Tokyo, Japan")
    find_restaurant("Tacos", "Jakarta, Indonesia")
    find_restaurant("Tapas", "Maputo, Mozambique")
    find_restaurant("Falafel", "Cairo, Egypt")
    find_restaurant("Spaghetti", "New Delhi, India")
    find_restaurant("Cappuccino", "Geneva, Switzerland")
    find_restaurant("Sushi", "Los Angeles, California")
    find_restaurant("Steak", "La Paz, Bolivia")
    find_restaurant("Gyros", "Sydney, Australia")
```

Comment: Try removing the `sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)` line (and the similar line for `std.stderr`.  It looks like this code was written for Python 2

Comment: @snakecharmerb: Correct, this solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @snakecharmerb: Can you formulate your comment as an answer? I don't see a way to accept your comment as the answer for the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[codecs.getwriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.getwriter) returns a [codecs.StreamWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.StreamWriter) instance which wraps a stream and writes to it using the encoding passed to `getwriter`.  In the code in the question, `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` are being wrapped with writers that will write UTF-8-encoded bytes to them

```py
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stderr)
```

However `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` are `text` streams, and so their `write` methods expect `str`, not `Bytes`.  Since the `StreamWriter` is passing bytes, the exception occurs.

Overriding `sys.stdout` like this is a technique used in Python2 to force a particular output encoding when piping output.

In this particular case, these two lines should be removed from the code.  If it's necessary to force output in a non-default encoding- then it's better to set the [PYTHONIOENCODING](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) environment variable.